# Azure Dev Ops: Undo Another User's Check-Out

Tags: azure-devops

I have Azure Dev Ops on premise which has a bunch of files that are checked out to a user on a machine that no longer exists.  How can I undo the check-out of those files?  I used to be able to do this through TFS Power Tools; but, there does not seem to be a tool that does the same thing for Azure Dev Ops.  Is there a GIT command that will do this instead?  How do I clean up Azure Dev Ops file check-outs?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Git is a distributed version control system. Each developer has a copy of the source repository on their dev machine. So it's supposed you are using TFVC version control, there is no GIT commands to work with TFVC version control. Check [Git & TFVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/comparison-git-tfvc?view=azure-devops).
2. TFS Power Tools is a client extension which needs to be installed by each user locally for their own version of VS. If you want to use Power Tools, you can use VS/Team Explorer 2015 and earlier versions.
3. You could use `tf undo` command to delete Team Foundation version control pending changes in another user's workspace:

   `tf undo /workspace:OtherUserWorkspace;OtherUser $/TeamProject /recursive /collection:http://YourTFSServer:8080/tfs/YourCollection`

   Check following link for more details:

   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/undo-changes-another-user-workspace?view=azure-devops

Comment: Thank you Cece Dong.  You sparked a thought for me.  I still have VS 2012 and that has Power Tools that allow me to do what I need.  Perhaps Microsoft will create a similar add-in for VS 2017 or 2019.